# Mongoose will not update document with new object property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Schema:

```
import Mongoose from 'mongoose'

const ThingSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },

  traits: {
    type: Object
  }
})

const Thing = Mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema)

export default Thing
```

The first time I created such a document and saved it in the DB I set a `name: 'something'` and a `traits: { propA: 1, propB: 2 }` and everything was saved correctly.

Now I want to update the document and set a new property inside `traits`:

```
let thingInDB = await ThingModel.findOne({ name: 'something' })
console.log(thingInDB.traits) // <-- it logs { propA: 1, propB: 2 } as expected 
thingInDB.traits.propC = 3
await thingInDB.save()
```

The above code is executed with no errors but when I look in the DB the new `propC` is not saved in `traits`. I've tried multiple times.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to declare every property of the object explicitly:

```
import Mongoose from 'mongoose'

const ThingSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },

  traits: {
    propA: {
      type: Number
    },
    propB: {
      type: Number
    },
    propC: {
      type: Number
    }
  }
})

const Thing = Mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema)

export default Thing
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `thingSchema.markModified("trait")` before the `.save()` method? It worked for me when I ran into a similar problem in the past.